# 3d race game collision detection

Tags: 3d, collision-detection

Can somebody explain how the collision detection works for race tracks in games like need for speed or wipeout?

Comment: What have you read so far?  What don't you understand?  There is a ton of information on Collision Detection on the net.  You should make some attempt at, you know, reading some of it first.

Answer (score 8):

I found a well illustrated [article](http://www.euclideanspace.com/threed/games/examples/cars/collisions/index.htm) describing collision detection between the cars in a racing game. It also has a general [description](http://www.euclideanspace.com/threed/animation/collisiondetect/index.htm) of the concepts of collision detection.

For the track collision detection you could use something like the color map approach discussed [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/game/97915/97915/collision-detection-for-racing-game/). Essentially you just draw a map containing your track in a distinct color. Then you read the color at the projected position of the car from the map - if it's the tracks color you have a collision.

I found another seemingly good [article](http://ubuntu-gamedev.wikispaces.com/2D+Collision+Detection) describing basic 2D collision detection algorithms.

HTH.